# list(map) error : TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using Python 3.6.3 in Anaconda.
And I'm trying:

```
observations = ["red", "white"] 
seen = np.array([[0,1,0]]).T
list(map(lambda x: observations[x], seen))
```

then this error occurred :

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

I checked the map:

```
map(lambda x: observations[x], seen)
map at 0x2ab8c869e80>
```

so I think I used `map` correctly. Just not sure how to show the map results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seen` is a list of lists, its element is a list and you're trying to use it as an index to list. Either remove outer square brackets in the definition of `seen`, or map over its concatenation.